# Handling large data in a C program

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-pool

I am working on a project which runs queries on a database and the results are greater than the memory size. I have heard of memory pool libraries but I'm not sure that it's the best way solution to this problem.
Do memory pool libraries support writing and reading back from disk (as the result of a query that needs to be parsed many times). Are there also some other ways to achieve this?

P.S
I am using MySQL Database and its C API to access database.

**EDIT**: here's an example:
Suppose I have five tables, each having a million rows. I want to find how much one table is similar to another, so I am creating a bloom filter for each table and then check each filter against the data in the rest of the four tables.

Comment: Not enough information, but if you could use cursors, then your results won't be greater than the memory size.

Comment: can you give an example? why you need to load huge data into memory?

Comment: @tuxuday I think query size is greater than memory. Moreover, user is trying to load all data to memory than user wishes to do some other operation.

Comment: @all I have edited the question with the example. The actual dataset is eve bigger. Please tell me if I have made the scenario clear enough so that it can be answered

Comment: You should leave operating system to do its job. Swapping+VM will solve your problem. However, if you want control in your hand. You should store result in ".tmp" file. Then, if it is not sorted, sort the file. Since it is sorted, you can do whatever you want but with some cost( seek time+latency..). Morover, you should avoid allocate the whole memory.

Answer (score 1):

Extending your logical memory beyond the physical memory by using secondary storage (e.g. disks) is usually called **swapping**, not memory pooling. Your operating system already does it for you, and you should try letting it do its job first.

Memory pool libraries provide more speed and real-time predictability to memory allocation by using fixed-size allocation, but don't increase your actual memory.

Comment: if the data size is greater than swap area + memory and query is random, what should you recommend ?

Comment: when I query to the database it returns a result set. Now I need to store this result set and for that I will need to allocate some memory dynamically. since this result is greaer than the size of RAM I have to take care than my program does not just allocates whole of the ram and let my system crash. where does `os` come in this process. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam: The OS provides you with logical memory, which is physical memory + swap. Your process never accesses physical memory directly.

Comment: to be specific what you are saying that my program can easily malloc some 6gb of memory on a 4 gb system without no loss in its robustness ( not to think of performance at the moment ). Am I correct.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam: If (a) your OS implements swapping (which most do) and (b) your address space is large enough (64 bit system) and (c) there is enough swap space, then yes.

Comment: ok, thanks. but let us suppose that we have to do it without that can you suggest something

Answer (score 1):

You should restructure your program to not use so much memory. Instead of pulling the "whole" (or large part) of the DB into memory you should use a cursor and **incrementally** update the datastructure your program is maintaining or incrementally change the metric you are querying.

EDIT: you added that you might want to run a bloom filter on the tables? 
Have a look at incremental bloom filters: [here](http://webee.technion.ac.il/people/or/publications/Infocom12_VICBF.pdf)

Comment: I need to parse the data n times now tell me how should I do it incrementally by querying the database only once. I know how to retrieve data in segments well but what I do not want to query the database again

Answer (score 0):

how about the [Physical Address Extension(PAE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension)

Comment: PAE extends the virtual memory of 32 bit systems, I doubt that this is the case. Also PAE should be avoided.